# How to open a port in El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, port, firewall

I am running Ruby on Rails on my Mac Book Pro on El Capitan and I would like to access my webpage from other computers.

How can I enable the port 3000 in the firewall?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can disable the firewall by following this path:

System Preferences > Security > Firewall

and you can see all list on the terminal by this code:

```
sudo ipfw list
```

Secondly, you can add specific port with two ways:

1. Command Terminal

   [1-Step]: type on terminal

   sudo vim /etc/pf.conf

[2-Step]: Add this line of end of file.

```
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 3000
```

[3-Step]: Test and reboot.

```
sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
reboot
```

Also, [this](https://rolfje.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/open-a-port-in-osx-mavericks-firewall/) is helpful blog post about your problem

2. [WaterRoof](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/) (GUI)

Good works!